# Safe async saving while modifying data?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am doing a little project where I am required to constantly simulate (modify) multiple super large object data at all times. The modifications are complicated like a linked meshes – a lot of the object's internal data are being thrown, swapped, and computed around as well.

However, I also want to perform a timed saving (DTO mapping + serialization) into multiple grouped files via async to prevent it from the constant stuttering, as the saving process is quite a tedious work.

Is it safe to save asynchronously while the data is being modified all the time? If not, what options can I make?

Meanwhile you might tell me to clone the object so it will become safe to save – but that's just moving away from what I am intended to do – the objects are really massive.

The project divides the process into two: Simulate object before checking for a save. So, yes it is only valid if the saving is done outside the simulation process. This is why I asked if it is safe for async, because I don't full understand it.

My next question is, will the saving happen inside the simulation process? If so, what other ways I can save without hindering the simulation speed? Or perhaps some pattern to be done to the async saving process so it wouldn't save inside the simulation process?

Comment: The real question is whether it is acceptable to save part of one state with part of another, or whether the object is only valid if frozen?

Comment: The project divides the process into two: Simulate object before checking for a save. So, yes it is only valid if the saving is done outside the simulation process. This is why I asked if it is safe for async, because I don't full understand it. Will the saving happen inside the simulation process? If so, what other ways I can save without hindering the simulation speed? Or perhaps some pattern to be done to the async saving process so it wouldn't save inside the simulation process?

Comment: async/await is used to free up a thread. Usually done from apps like WPF so the GUI thread does not hang and ASP.NET so the thread can serve another incoming request. It has nothing to do with parallel processing or multithreading. The save operation will take equally as long either way and will fail or succeed based on the same rules. So in a nut shell your business logic should not be influenced either way.

Comment: Oh, so the async is only for the GUI applications? My project isn't a GUI. It's... well... Game project. What I mentioned about the objects are actually the game objects-- not simple ones, though.

Comment: Well if there is a main message pump or if the thread being used for the save should be released as soon as possible then async/await could be of use. Another indicator is does the app type support it natively. A console app does not and neither does a windows service. WPF does and so does ASP.NET. Not sure what is hosting your code but that might be a good indicator of which way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Async is like multi-thread, although does not create any thread, which I don't really understand why. In that case, I won't able to save the objects while simulating them as the IO will interrupt the simulation.

- Async IO is not safe.
- Saving will happen inside the simulation process.
- Solution is to stop and cache parts of the objects within the simulation when it's not used at some point, this will both boosts performance, and allows the cached objects to be saved. The saving process is queued, where the task for saving the objects will be executed one by one with conditions below.

Async tasking conditions:

- If the object were to be reactivated into the simulation again before the task for saving the queued objects were started, the saving will be canceled, and the objects will be reactivated without interruption. The saving moves on to the next queued object instead.
- If the object were to be reactivated while saving, the thread has to be waited until the task for saving that particular object is finally done.